# Copy to clipboard from Firefox add-on content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, copy, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to write a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) in a Firefox add-on that will copy a string to the user's clipboard in response to an event. I know that I can do this with the [Firefox clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/clipboard) like this:

```
var clipboard = require("sdk/clipboard");
var val = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
alert('copying "' + val + '" to clipboard');
clipboard.set(val);
```

But trying to access the clipboard API in a content script produces this error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

To solve this, I think I might need to [interact with a page script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts) somehow, but after reading the documentation, I'm still not sure how to do it. Can anyone post sample code or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work with `onAttach`. Here's my `main.js`:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var clipboard = require("sdk/clipboard");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: 'example.com',
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url('content-script.js'),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on('copyToClipboard', function(request) {
            clipboard.set(request);
        });
    }
});
```

And `content-script.js`:

```
self.port.emit('copyToClipboard', 'This text will be copied.');
```